# Передать в функцию двойной указатель по ссылке

Tags: c++, указатели

```
char** ptr;

void func(&ptr) //ошибка компиляции
{
    ...
}

func(ptr);
```

Comment: Тип аргумента функции указать-то надо бы.

Comment: @MortielDarksi  Если у вас возникла потребность передать двойной указатель по ссылке, то скорей всего, что вы делаете что-то неправильно.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У `&` должен быть тип:

```
void func(char**& ptr) {...}
```